# How to find duplicate (repeated ) comma separated values in different excel cells?

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, count

I have students numbers mentioned in comma separated values in cells, in one excel sheet different cell contains the numbers. so how to find the student numbers which are repeated in different cells.

I tried to solve it by using function COUNTIF but student number are too many, so, I have to run function for each number

[image]

Comment: So what is the expected output? Is it `student 1 = 5`? And so on?

Answer (score 0):

Since I suppose that you don't have a reason to keep the data in the shown format your best option is treating your data as a comma delimited format:
[image]

This splits the data in multiple columns allowing you to easily count all the observations with simple `COUNTIF`